# What's the correct form: "pets island" or '"pet's island"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, possessives, apostrophe, orthography

I'm trying to write a short paragraph about an animal island and I'm a bit confused as to what would be the correct sentence to use for the title.

Comment: Neither. It would normally be [**Pet Island.**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pets+island%2Cpet%27s+island%2Cpet+island&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Like the [**Pet Sematary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_Sematary) movies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['User Manual' or 'User's Manual'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/user-manual-or-users-manual)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I seem to remember a lively discussion of _pet's corner_ versus  _pets corner_; maybe it was on this site? I don't recall what, if any, the outcome was. I still wonder about _pets' corner_.